# How can I create an Lambda Expression for Linq in the Where clause for two tables after the Join?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have this,

```
 Expression<Func<MyCourse, bool>> filter = mc => mc.Active == 1;
 Func<MyCourse, bool> funcWhere = filter.Compile();
```

and then this,

```
var myClasses = db.MyCourse.Join(db.People, mc => mc.PersonId, 
p => p.PersonId, (mc, p) => new { MyCourse= mc, Person = p }).Where(???)
```

The reason I need to do it this way is because if I put the filter on the MyCourse table first with,

```
db.MyCourse.Where(funcWhere).Join....
```

The SQL created brings back all of the People and all of the MyCourse and then uses the filter.  If I do the where at the end,

```
(mc, p) => new { MyCourse= mc, Person = p }).Where(mc=>mc.MyCourse.Active == 1)
```

I get a good query with the Joins.  Else the engine queries all the rows into memory first.  Two separate queries with thousands of rows.

I have seen a tremendous amount of questions on SO and elsewhere about this.  I cannot find one that tells me how to do the Expression when there is more than one table, from a Join, using a dynamic `Where Expression<Func<T,TResult>>`.

The goal is to make a dynamic query statement based upon Expressions (not [Dynamic Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/), and no third party.)  In fact, this question claims the Where at the end is slower, but in my program it does the correct query with Joins.

MyCourse has a PersonId and People has a PersonId.  If I wrote this by hand it'd look like,

```
select mc.CourseName, p.LastName 
from MyCourse mc inner join Person p on mc.PersonId = p.PersonId
where mc.Active = 1;
```

(Those are just example columns for the question.  They're not really what I want from the above query, except Active == 1.)

[Where clause with Join in lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489681/where-clause-with-join-in-lambda-expression)

Update:  FWIW, I was able to get it working this this,

```
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass), "MyClassDebug");
    var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(param, dbParameter),
            Expression.Constant(dbValue)
        ),
        param
    );
```

I did not do navigation properties or anything else.  And I was able to use it like this,

```
var MyQuery = (from recs in dbcontext.MyClass.Where(exp)
               ...three joins
```

The produced SQL looked good, and the Explain plan showed minimal row retrieval.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? And is `PeopleId` in your `MyCourse` table a foreign key?

Comment: Yes.  It is a foreign key in name only, not at the database defined as such.

Comment: I see. It would be easier if it was since Entity Framework would create a reference list for you from your Person class. But anyway, it is still possible to do.

Comment: For one, the start of the query should be `db.MyCourse.Where(filter)`. But I think that depending on your EF version you should look for the various global query filter options.

Comment: @GertArnold The problem is when I use it that way, Linq brings back all the Person records, 36k and then adjusts the rows for the Active courses.  If I put the filter at the end of it with the expression typed out x=>x.MyCourse.Active == 1, then I get a single query with a Join (from what I see on the SQL Profiler).

Comment: @GabrielLuci I added the keys.  It did not help on the query creation.

Comment: Really? It would be the same as starting with `db.MyCourse.Where(mc => mc.Active == 1)`. Hard to believe that *that* will be evaluated as `IEnumerable` . Which EF version is this? (Always relevant use the appropriate version tags).

Comment: Are you using EF Core? In any case, you can't use a `Func` to pass to SQL, you need an `Expression<Func<>>`. You can't reference an anonymous object easily to create a "dynamic" filter without tricky generic method use, so what you need is to have the `Join` return a real class (`class Joined { public MyCourse MyCourse; public People Person; }`) and then you can use that real class in the filter `Expression` creation.

Comment: what's wrong with the query `db.MyCourse.Where(filter).Join ...` as given in some answer? I think that's the correct approach, a very clear way to help the expression builders understand what you want to generate the equivalent sql query.

Comment: As soon as you use expressions (and not `Func`s) and don't call `ToList`, `AsEnumerable` etc., applying `Where` before the `Join` is perfectly fine. e.g. `db.MyCourse.Where(filter).Join....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect calling `Compile()` on your `Expression` is causing your trouble. Your full query includes the `Join`, but you've already compiled the `Where` clause, so it can't compile the entire query including the `Join` together. That might be why it's grabbing the entire table because it's executing the `Where` by itself first, then doing the `Join` later.

But you don't need to call `Compile()`. Just pass the `Expression` into `Where()`:

```
Expression<Func<MyCourse, bool>> filter = mc => mc.Active == 1;
var myClasses = db.MyCourse
    .Where(filter)
    .Join(db.People, mc => mc.PersonId, 
p => p.PersonId, (mc, p) => new { MyCourse= mc, Person = p }).ToList();
```

Somewhat unrelated to your actual problem, but if you created the foreign keys, you can simplify this a bit. Update your model in your Visual Studio project if you haven't already. Your `Person` class will change to have a list of `MyCourse` and your `MyCourse` class will have a list of `Person`.

So you can do something like:

```
Expression<Func<MyCourse, bool>> filter = mc => mc.Active == 1;
var courses = db.MyCourse.Include("Person").Where(filter);
foreach (var course in courses) {
    var person = course.Person; //This is populated with the Person record
}
```

Linq handles the join, and each `MyCourse` returned will have a `Person` property.